# BIOS boot priority lists not showing up

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, elementaryos

[image: https://imgur.com/a/gCMdNnB]

I have a laptop running elementary OS for a month now. Currently, I have to install Windows for an app and my system is pretty low-end so I can't use Virtual Machine

I want to install Windows from BIOS like usual, but I can't find the usual boot priority list. I tried load the default settings, enabled/disabled secure boot and fast boot, but nothing changed. Did I mess up some settings?

Comment: It would be helpful to know which Windows version you are trying to install along with the method you are using to install it.

Comment: And also what you're trying to install it _from_. Are you using a Rufus-created USB stick?

Comment: I'm installing the newest windows 10 (2004), from the microsoft site. Using USB stick created from elementary OS Image Burner.

Comment: Ah, I don't think Windows ISOs are directly writable to USB sticks – they're strictly just ISO-9660 CD images.

Comment: well, but at least the device name should shows up? I'll try to burn linux then.

Comment: No, because you're using an UEFI system where devices have quite different requirements to be recognized as "bootable".

Comment: Well, the linux actually showed up! I guess that means I should get a suitable windows image. I didn't consider the image was the problem because the BIOS boot menu was different from the last time I used it. Big thanks @user1686!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that Windows ISOs are just that, pure ISO 9660 images meant for writing to CD/DVDs. They do not have the "hybrid" build that Linux distros tend to add. So because the data structure used in CD/DVDs stores boot data in a different location than HDD/USB/SSDs do, a pure CD image will not usually make a bootable USB stick.

Second thing is that your computer has UEFI firmware and is using UEFI boot process, which is again different from the previously common IBM PC BIOS boot process. Where previously BIOS firmware would list *all* devices which had some data in their MBR boot sector (whether it was valid or not), UEFI firmware has much stricter requirements – it expects the bootable device to have *a specific file* at a specific location in the 1st partition, and if your USB stick doesn't have one, then it won't be listed because it definitely is *not* bootable in UEFI mode.

So instead of looking for a "suitable Windows image" (Microsoft does not provide any), you'll need to use a tool that specifically knows how to extract the ISO image's contents into a USB stick.

From Linux, you can create a Windows USB stick using CLI tools:

1. Extract the ISO file into a new directory (e.g. using `7z`).
2. Use `wimsplit` to cut the 'Sources/Install.wim' file into 4000 MB pieces, as usually it's larger than the FAT32 size limit. (Delete the original .wim once you have the .swm parts.)
3. Clean out and reformat the USB stick (using GParted, GNOME Disks, or fdisk/mkfs.fat). It needs to have just one ordinary FAT32 partition.
4. Copy all the files into the empty USB stick, keeping the overall layout intact.